# 'forfiles' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I ran the code in Windows 7 and it is working fine... when I run this code in Windows XP, I am getting forfiles not recognized.

```
call :moveOldFiles D:\coupon\Source\1 *.* %days% D:\coupon\Destination\3 >>D:\coupon\logs\log.txt

:moveOldFiles  sourceDir  extension  minAgeInDays  destinationDir
forfiles /p "%~f1" /m %2 /d -%3 -c "cmd /c move /y @path ""%~f4\"" && echo @path moved to "%~f4"""
exit /b
```

Comment: forfiles.exe can be downloaded for Windows XP from Microsoft.  It is not in the default installation.

Answer (score 0):

forfiles is not available on XP.  However, it is part of the Resource Kit.